# Getting rid of empty elements in a vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am trying a write a program where it takes in 5 or more animal names from the user and arranges in a numerical order. However, when I put a space for an animal, it includes the space in the numerical order instead of ignoring it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include<algorithm>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

void isolateAnimals() {
    cout << "Enter at least five animal names, e.g., cat, dog, etc..." << endl;
    string animals;
    vector<string>animalVector;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= animalVector.size(); i++) {
        getline(cin, animals);
        animalVector.push_back(animals);
        if (i>4 && animals == " ")
            break;
    }

    // this is the part where im trying to get rid of the empty element
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= animalVector.size()+1; i++) {

        if(animalVector[i].size()>0){
            if (animalVector[i].empty())
                 animalVector.erase(animalVector.begin()+i);

        }
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < animalVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << animalVector[i] << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    isolateAnimals();
}
```

Comment: if `animalVector[i].size()>0` is true, then `animalVector[i].empty()` will also always be false.

Comment: even when i take out animalVector[i].size()>0, it still doesnt work

Comment: A string containing a space character is not the same as an empty string.

Comment: Why not add `if(animals != " ")` before `animalVector.push_back(animals);`? Alternatively, move `animalVector.push_back(animals);` *after* `if(...) break;`

Comment: Your loop is suspicious: `for (unsigned i = 0; i <= animalVector.size(); i++)`, you start with empty `animalVector` and add element to it in each loop. better to just have `for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {getline(cin, animals); if (animals == " ") { break; } animalVector.push_back(animals); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop will terminate if you've pushed 5 strings onto the vector AND if the user enters a single space character.  When you try to clean up the vector later, you are searching for an empty string. That is not the same thing.

Allow me to suggest a less freaky-looking input loop than what you have (I elected to use empty line to terminate, instead of a space):

```
while(getline(cin, animals)) {
    if (!animals.empty())
        animalVector.push_back(animals);
    else if(animalVector.size() >= 5)
        break;
}
```

The above checks your input *before* adding it to the vector.  It also aborts properly if the input stream enters an error state.  This means you don't need to do the clean-up loop later.

Now, you are welcome to add extra checks to sanitize your inputs.  That could be stuff like removing spaces from the string before checking if it's empty, *etc*.

Comment: void isolateAnimals() {
 cout << "Enter at least five animal names, e.g., cat, dog, etc..." << endl;
 string animals;
 vector<string>animalVector;
 for (unsigned i = 0; i <= animalVector.size(); i++) {
  getline(cin, animals);
  while(getline(cin, animals)) {
            if (!animals.empty())
                animalVector[i].push_back(animals);
            else if(animalVector.size() >= 5)
                break;
}
  
 
 }    I tried what you suggested but it gives me this error:  no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<char>::push_back(std::string&)'

Comment: i tried what you suggested but it gives me this error:  no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<char>::push_back(std::string&)'

Comment: It was a typo.  I wrote this in a hurry.  I would hope that you realized the error.  In any case, I've edited to fix.